# Is there a closed form or series representation for this linear recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Define the linear recurrence $a_n=F_na_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ with $a_0=1$, $a_1=2$, and $F_n$ being the Fibonacci series ($F_0=F_1=1$). Is there a possible closed form for $a_n$, or even a series representation? I've looked at several resources, but many of them just deal with recurrences with constant coefficients.

Comment: Check again your recursive formula.

Comment: Is the second term really $an$, or did you mean $a_n$, or even $a_{n-2}$?

Comment: I have often seen two definitions of Fibonacci series. Either $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$ or $F_0=F_1=1$. Which definition are you using here?

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Sorry, forgot an underscore

Comment: This is [A026822](https://oeis.org/A026822) in OEIS. There's not much more information there.